# HTTP 500 error after plugin install

Tags: plugins, errors, 500-internal-error

I use WordPress 4.9.1 with the theme *Newsmag*. I tried to install some additional plugins, like *bbPress* and *Media Library Folders*. These are popular and common plugins, but after installation, I got error HTTP 500 on administration panel. I have to disable all the installed plugins in SQL database to recover site. There are several plugins, that are installed and enabled without this error, just like Akeeba Backup.

Comment: Edit your `wp-config.php` to set `WP_DEBUG` to _true_ and enable the plugins one by one to discover the culprit of the 500 error.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to disable a plugin when there is no access to admin, is renaming of plugin folder.

Connect via ftp by Filezilla, for example. Find plugin folder and put dot before its folder name. This should look like

```
wp-content/plugins/.bbpress/
```

Such folder names are ignored by WordPress. Update the admin page and you will see that bbpress is removed from the plugin list.

Comment: I see, I know it, but not sure why I got `HTTP 500` when I install plugins.

Comment: Your question says "I have to disable all the installed plugins in SQL database to recover site", and it does not contain the word "why". So I have answered to your question as it was formulated.

Comment: 500 - a general php error in plugin. It can be caused by a million of reasons. Some kind of incompatibility. Every case is different.

Comment: How could I debug it? These are popular plugins, so should work.

Comment: The best way is to use debugger like xDebug+phpStorm. Or, you can try to install WP PHP Console plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-php-console/ and look at errors reported in browser console. You can also use standard WP debugging tools https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress or check php logs on server, if you have access to.